# Marshalling C++ Struct with function pointers in C#

Tags: c#, c++, unmanaged, managed, pointer-to-member

Im making a C# managed extension dll for NPS witch looks like this:

```
    public enum RADIUS_CODE
    {
        rcUnknown = 0,
        rcAccessRequest = 1,
        rcAccessAccept = 2,
        rcAccessReject = 3,
        rcAccountingRequest = 4,
        rcAccountingResponse = 5,
        rcAccessChallenge = 11,
        rcDiscard = 256
    }

    public enum RADIUS_EXTENSION_POINT
    {
        repAuthentication,
        repAuthorization
    }

    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Winapi)]
    public delegate ref RADIUS_ATTRIBUTE_ARRAY GetRequestDelegate(ref RADIUS_EXTENSION_CONTROL_BLOCK ECB);

    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Winapi)]
    public delegate ref RADIUS_ATTRIBUTE_ARRAY GetResponseDelegate(ref RADIUS_EXTENSION_CONTROL_BLOCK ECB, RADIUS_CODE rcResponseType);

    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Winapi)]
    public delegate uint SetResponseTypeDelegate(ref RADIUS_EXTENSION_CONTROL_BLOCK ECB, RADIUS_CODE rcResponseType);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct RADIUS_EXTENSION_CONTROL_BLOCK
    {
        public uint cbSize;
        public uint dwVersion;
        public RADIUS_EXTENSION_POINT repPoint;
        public RADIUS_CODE rcRequestType;
        public RADIUS_CODE rcResponseType;
        public GetRequestDelegate GetRequest;
        public GetResponseDelegate GetResponse;
        public SetResponseTypeDelegate SetResponseType;
    }

    [DllExport("RadiusExtensionProcess2", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi)]
    public static uint RadiusExtensionProcess2(ref RADIUS_EXTENSION_CONTROL_BLOCK pECB)
    {
        //var result = pECB.SetResponseType(ref pECB, RADIUS_CODE.rcAccessAccept);
        return 0;
    }
```

NPS passed a control block to the function that contains 5 fields and 3 pointers to functions, the fields map correctly but i cant get the functions working.
If I uncomment the line before the return NPS discard the request noting that the dll crashed, with the line commented out NPS processes the request successfully.
I'm well versed in assembly and C# but a newbie at C++ and managed/unmamaged interop.
I've tried all sorts of marshaling methods, calling conventions that i could find and stepping thru the disassembly but this is as far as I've gotten after a week and I'm out of ideas...
The documentation I've been going by can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb892004(v=vs.85).aspx)

**Some Progress**

I had previously tried `Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer` as suggested by @RonBeyer with no success but it's working now, i think i was missing some 
`ref` keywords at that time, so this seem to be working

```
    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Winapi)]
    public delegate ref RADIUS_ATTRIBUTE AttributeAtDelegate([In] ref RADIUS_ATTRIBUTE_ARRAY Array, [In] uint dwIndex);

    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Winapi)]
    public delegate uint GetSizeDelegate([In] ref RADIUS_ATTRIBUTE_ARRAY Array);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct RADIUS_ATTRIBUTE_ARRAY
    {
        public uint cbSize;
        public IntPtr Add;
        public IntPtr AttributeAt;
        public IntPtr GetSize;
        public IntPtr InsertAt;
        public IntPtr RemoveAt;
        public IntPtr SetAt;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct RADIUS_ATTRIBUTE
    {
        public uint dwAttrType;
        public RADIUS_DATA_TYPE fDataType;
        public uint cbDataLength;
        public IntPtr lpValue;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct RADIUS_EXTENSION_CONTROL_BLOCK
    {
        public uint cbSize;
        public uint dwVersion;
        public RADIUS_EXTENSION_POINT repPoint;
        public RADIUS_CODE rcRequestType;
        public RADIUS_CODE rcResponseType;
        public IntPtr GetRequest;
        public IntPtr GetResponse;
        public IntPtr SetResponseType;
    }

    [DllExport("RadiusExtensionProcess2", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi)]
    public static uint RadiusExtensionProcess2(ref RADIUS_EXTENSION_CONTROL_BLOCK pECB)
    {
        GetRequestDelegate GetRequest = (GetRequestDelegate)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(pECB.GetRequest, typeof(GetRequestDelegate));
        GetResponseDelegate GetResponse = (GetResponseDelegate)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(pECB.GetResponse, typeof(GetResponseDelegate));
        SetResponseTypeDelegate SetResponseType = (SetResponseTypeDelegate)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(pECB.SetResponseType, typeof(SetResponseTypeDelegate));

        uint SetResponseTypeResult = SetResponseType(ref pECB, RADIUS_CODE.rcAccessAccept); //SetResponseTypeResult is 0 and NPS sends a access granted message

        RADIUS_ATTRIBUTE_ARRAY AttrArray = GetRequest(ref pECB);

        return 0;
    }
```

`SetResponseType` works without crashing the dll and `GetRequest` returns the expected value for cbSize and what look like valid pointers for the functions defined in the `RADIUS_ATTRIBUTE_ARRAY` struct.
So i proceeded to map `AttributeAt` and `GetSize` the same way but the data they return is nonsence.
I double and triple checked the definitions [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb891987(v=vs.85).aspx) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb891992(v=vs.85).aspx) but so far i haven't been able to get the proper data from these functions, since the dll dosen't crash and i dont get null back, i can only assume there is something wrong with how I'm passing the parameters to the functions
On that note, are the in/out keywords in the C++ function definitions just info for developers or do they effect how parameters are handled on the stack?

Comment: Maybe [`Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer<TDelegate> Method (IntPtr)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn261456(v=vs.110).aspx) would be of some use, although I'm not sure if you should be storing your delegates as `IntPtr` in the structure, or the delegate type...

Comment: @RonBeyer Thank you for the comment, i did try that as well previously but it looks like i make some progress this time, I updated my post